# Has the old-style notification bar returned for some purposes?

Tags: support, user-interface, notifications, answered-questions

For the first time in a *very* long while, I saw the old-style notification banner!

[image: screenshot showing old-style notification banner for new answers]

For quite some time, I've seen more discreet notifications of new answers, appearing within the page itself, just above where I compose my answer.

This harkens back to *many* months ago.

Is this intended behavior, or a bug? If it is intended, does this always happen for notifying users of new answers while they're composing their answer? Does it happen for other situations also?

Or is this intended but not normal (e.g., reflecting a problem with my browser, causing Stack Exchange to fall back on an older way of doing things).

New-style notifications still seem to still work fine (for things like comment and chat pings, edits on my posts, and badges).

In case it's relevant, I'm using Chromium, which reports its version as `23.0.1271.97 Ubuntu 11.10 (23.0.1271.97-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears they are still around under certain circumstances.  I ran into one myself while editing a question.  Not exactly the same thing you had but similar.

[image]

I wonder if this has to do with some of the changes that have happened recently:

- Stack Exchange Inc has recently moved their data centers to another location in NYC. (There was a blog post somewhere out there on this, but I can't find it now, links would be helpful)
- The recent build [update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/203389)

Or perhaps because the older notifications are longer and provide more information.

**Update**

I've seen this several times since I posted this, but forgot to mention it here.

[image]

I have a feeling these are *supposed* to be here, because once when I was using a test account it asked me to add a password, and kept asking me, so I don't think this is a bug necessarily..

[image]

Comment: Does the old-style bar appear reliably for you, under these circumstances?

Comment: @EliahKagan  I've never edited a question for so long, so I haven't had an opportunity to find out.  I'll report back if I do.  Maybe you should ask on MSO?